# For Surface Book 2 how to use dedicated video with dock station

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, microsoft-surface

I am using Surface Book 2, with its original dock station, where I have wired 2 Lenovo T2454 monitors. I wanted to force SB2 to use only the dedicated GPU (not integrated one), but I cannot seem to be able to get it done.

From Nvidia Control Panel, I have selected the preferred video, but it does not seem to help as in task manager I can see only the integrated one is used.

I tried disabling the integrated video from Device Manager, but once I do that, the monitors disappear as devices, turn off and also no longer appear in Display Settings - the laptop cannot detect them.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe the docking station only supports the integrated GPU?

Comment: How can we find out if this is the case?

Comment: Ask Microsoft??